# python - stop audio between words

Tags: python, audio

I want to make a simple script that uses audio files to talk a user through a process. When the user has finished the current step, it should stop trying to explain that step and move into the next. This is easy to do, except that it sounds very ugly and unnatural when the audio stops mid-word.

I've noticed in Grand Theft Auto 5, when a character is talking and something unexpected happens, the audio pauses **between words** and then resumes at the beginning of the sentence a few seconds later -- which sounds very natural, because that's how people really speak.

I'd like to find a way to do this with my script. It doesn't need to resume at the beginning of the sentence, because it's responding the the user being ready to move on, but I'd like it to somehow find the spaces between words and pause there. Is there a simple way to do this in Python, or maybe an easier way to do it in something else, assuming that it's not simple in Python?

Edit: The audio has yet to be recorded, so if there's some way I should record it to make this happen, I can do that. I'm aware that GTA5 had a team of programmers, and I'm just one guy making a simple script -- but it seems like there should be a simple solution, like something that looks for silence in the audio, or maybe marking the spaces between words by hand?

Comment: How are you playing the audio? What librar(y|ies) are you using? Where are you getting the audio? What have you tried?

Comment: GTA 5 costed millions in development and lip-syncing. You want "a simple script". Won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know how you recorded your text but if you call every word in an other line you can type `import time` at line 1 and and then after every audio file you could set `time.sleep(0.3)` (0.3 stands for 0.3 seconds). but that may take a while. it would be useful to see your code. so can you send it maybe?